What do building one's cross and limbo mean?
https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=matlock-2024&episode=s01e03 says:

Build your cross step-by-step. And tomorrow don't just give 'em hell,
give them the damn heavens, limbo, and everything in between.

What does building one's cross mean?
What does the second sentence mean?
Are hell, heavens, and limbo three different after-death destinations? Why is only heavens plural and the other two singular?

Limbo. I don't know why he made heavens plural - the plural is usually used when using the word to mean the sky. Probably just a slip of the tongue.

is limbo different from hell?

Possibly professional casual jargon for "cross-examination" as in a court of law.   It is advice on how to question the witness in a methodical manner that progresses.

Tim, you can look limbo up.

I've downvoted because the title of your question suggests some laziness and it's actually two questions

Have you looked up "give em hell"? Do you know what it means? Do you know what any of the words mean?

heaven, hell and limbo.

@TimR - I always wanted to go to Limbo because of the dancing.

Not aimed at anyone in particular, but... whether Belinda Carlisle was right, or not, that 'Heaven is a place on Earth', I think I am on safe ground in asserting that when used as locations, the words Earth,  Limbo, Heaven, and Hell are just as much proper nouns as Egypt, Lebanon, Haiti, and Hungary, and, like them, need to be started with a capital letter.

@MichaelHarvey   I'm sure you'd bend over backwards to get there :-)

@TimR - I am lapsed C of E; my wife is a lapsed Catholic, since the age of 10 she says. She reminded me that I had forgotten to mention Purgatory, as did the scriptwriter in the OP. Interestingly, although Purgatory is still part of official Catholic doctrine, Limbo never was, and a 2007 document has downgraded it from a 'common doctrine' to a 'possible theological hypothesis'. The dear old C of E does not believe in "Limbo" or "Purgatory".

@TimR - I am reminded of the story of the Jewish guy who collapses in the street in New York, and, feeling death approach, asks the people helping him to find a rabbi. One is not nearby, but a rather zealous young Catholic priest presses forward. 'Do you know you are dying?' he asks. 'Yes' says the poor man. 'Do you believe in the Father, the Son, and the Holy Ghost?' demands the priest. 'I'm dying and you're asking me riddles already!' says the patient.

@MichaelHarvey At age 10 is precocious lapsing.

@TimR - it took me until 14, although for some time my 'belief' had been a sort of half-hearted assent. My family didn't go to church on Sundays, and our adherence to the Church of England was probably a tribal thing. My wife's father was a fanatically devout Catholic. When, aged 10, she told him she didn't believe in God any more, he said 'Never mind, you must still go to Mass', thus confirming her view of him as a hypocrite.

In the legal context of this show, "cross" is short for "cross examination", when a lawyer asks questions of an opponent's witness. So "build your cross" means planning the questions she's going to ask the witness.
"Give them hell" is an idiom for making thing very bad for the opposition by being extremely fierce; a military commander might say this to inspire the troops, and a coach may say it to their team. The second part of the sentence extends this metaphor to make it more extreme. The heavens and limbo are other places that people go after death, according to some religions.
It doesn't really make sense in the context of the metaphor. The origin of the idiom is that Hell is bad, so giving someone hell means sending bad stuff at them. Therefore, giving someone heaven would presumably be good for them, not bad. But the character is intending this to mean "throw everything you have at them".

Thanks. Which religions have concept limbo?

Roman Catholicism. It's where unbaptised souls go when they die.

@Barmar and Tim - Limbo (spelled thus) is not an official doctrine of the Catholic Church.

@MichaelHarvey I'm not a religious scholar, and this is not a religion site. That's what the word means to Catholics, regardless of doctrine.
